# Why are my List values being overwritten?

Tags: c++, arrays, list

I currently have created a small program to learn about Lists. I allow the user to add random integers to the List. It adds them fine simply using `DList.insert(number, position)`. Everything works fine for the first iteration, but when I allow the user to enter more random numbers, it gets rid of the previous numbers and then adds some more random numbers.

Since I'm new (rarely use it to program) to C++, I'm thinking that I'm making a very simple mistake. The issue seems to be that I'm just overwriting the old values in the List rather than adding new ones.

Here is what I'm doing,

```
List testList;
//Ask user for a number of elements to add
int num = get_number();
addRandInts(testList, num);
//I then give the user the option to add more or quit
```

Here is my `addRandInts`:

```
void addRandInts(List dl, int num) 
{
    int random_max = 999;
    int numIterations = dl.getSize() + num;

    if(num > 0) {
        cout << "Array Size: " << dl.getSize() << endl;
        for(int i = dl.getSize(); i < numIterations; i++) {
            dl.insert(rand() % random_max + 1, i); 
        }
    } else {
        cout << "You need to enter a positive integer" << endl;
    }
    dl.display(cout);
 }
```

I can provide my `List.insert(List, pos)` method if need be.

Here is the example output:

```
Please enter an integer number for the list: 5
Current Size: 0
42  486  341  527  189

//chance to add more to list
Please enter an integer number for the list: 3
Current Size: 0
740  490  388
```

So on the second run I was thinking that I should have the size of 5 and it should be adding 3 to it.
Since I'm new to pointers and the like, should I be passing a pointer to the list rather than the list?

Comment: There's obviously a bug in your implementation of list, why would post everything except the code from the list?

Comment: @DanielKO I felt that my error was coming from the posted code. I wasn't 100% positive which is why I mentioned that I would post my `insert()` code if it was needed/requested. I believe Jeremy is correct in that I was passing my value rather than reference.

Comment: Even if you were to pass a copy, inserting in a copy should not modify the original, so you have a problem in your copy constructor too; most likely the destructor of the copy is messing up the original. Why does the code say "Array size" and the output shows "Current size"? Also, the loop to insert looks wrong, you should be looping from 0 to `num`; what does the `pos` parameter in the `insert` is supposed to mean? What does `List.insert(List, pos)` mean? Do you insert a list into another?

Comment: @DanielKO I was changing it on the fly when adding it into SO. I can add my copy constructor if you'd like. However, after testing the pass by reference, the output seems to be correct. I recently edited the main post and I believe I fixed my loop. I apologize, I'm learning C++ (along with Data Structures) at the moment, so lots of this is new. Also, pos parameter is the position I'm inserting the values in. In my case, I'm just adding them onto the end of the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing the list into the addRantInts() function by value, which means the function is modifying a copy of the list rather than the original.  To avoid this, pass it by reference instead:

```
void addRandInts(List & dl, int num)    // <-- note ampersand!
```

Comment: Java habits die hard ;) Thank you for pointing this out. I believe I have a logic error in my `addRandInts() function as well (int the for loop). It seems to be keeping the first values added but not adding the extras.